# Delete FileInfo using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, fileinfo

I am getting the following message when trying to delete FileInfo:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Here is my code:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<FileInfo> duplicatedFiles = Fso.GetAllDuplicatedFiles(@"C:\", true);

            duplicatedFiles.Cast<FileInfo>().Select(f => f.Delete());
        }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` selects something, [`FileInfo.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) is `void`. But a LINQ query should not cause side effects anyway.
Apart from that, why do you cast a `FileInfo` to `FileInfo`?

You can use [`List.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=VS.110).aspx) which isn't LINQ:

```
List<FileInfo> duplicatedFiles = Fso.GetAllDuplicatedFiles(@"C:\", true);
duplicatedFiles.ForEach(fi => fi.Delete());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Select` is intended for *projecting data*, not for performing side-effects.

Simply use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(FileInfo fileInfo in duplicatedFiles)
{
    fileInfo.Delete();
}
```

Comment: LINQ is not the appropriate choice for performing side-effects.

Comment: see answer from Tim Schmelter

Comment: @MichaelSander: `List<T>.ForEach` is *not* LINQ. Secondly, read this - many recommend not using that method at all. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: overlooked this, sorry, youre right, ForEach is also not linq, sorry!